# Deploy to Heroku from parse server example successfully but repo size 0

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, migration, migrate, parse-server

I have deployed the Parse-Server-Example to the Heroku directly through the github and it is successfully deployed, but my Heroku App dashboard shows that the repo size is 0.

Could you help me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Heroku repo size will be zero because you are linking parse-server through github and it's not stored on Heroku. What you can do to change this is clone your repo by installing Heroku command line tools and this command.

```
heroku git:clone -a project-name
```

Make whatever changes you like and push back to heroku by using

```
git push heroku master
```

After pushing your project to Heroku it should tell you the size of your repo.